# Вынес JS код в отдельный файл. Тормозит

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Есть небольшой скрипт на сайте.
так вот я давно его писал и поэтому оно написано как попало. теперь решил привести код в порядок... Но как говорится - не ремонтируй пока работает))) 
рассмотрим 3 файла(упрощённая схема)

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!-- Подключаем JavaScript-файл с нашим сценарием, который и будет получать данные об автомобилях -->
 <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
 <!-- Подключение скрипта PCL's Nice Tooltip -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pcl_tooltip.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- при загрузке боди, подключается скрипт. может влияет. решил указать-->
<body onload="PCL_TooltipInit();"> 
 <div id="form"> 
  <form id="searchFormx">
   <div id="marki">
    <select id="select_marka">
     <option value="">Выберите марку</option>
     <?php foreach($marki as $marka): ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $marka['marka_id'];?>"><?php echo $marka['marka_name'];?></option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div id="modele"> </div>
   <div id="cars"></div>
  </form> 
  <div id="info"></div>
  <div style=" width:100%; height:1px; clear:both;"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="msg"></div>
 <div id="search-result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

search.php

```html
<?php if(isset($_POST['marka_id']) && $_POST['marka_id'] != ""): ?>
 <?php 
  $marka_id = $_POST['marka_id'];
  $modele = getModel($marka_id);
 ?>
 <select id="select_model">
   <option value="">Выберите модель</option>
   <?php foreach($modele as $model): ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $model['model_id'];?>"><?php echo $model['model_name'];?></option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(isset($_POST['model_id']) && $_POST['model_id'] != ""): ?>
 <?php 
  $model_id = $_POST['model_id'];
  $cars = getCars($model_id);
 ?>
 <select id="select_car">
   <option value="">Выберите модификацию</option>
   <?php foreach($cars as $car): ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $car['car_id'];?>"><?php echo $car['car_name'];?></option>  
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select> 

<?php endif; ?>
<!-- не видит скрипт по относительному пути, пришлось абсолютный писать, и добавление async не помогло-->
<script src="абсолютный путь к файлу/custom.js" async></script>
```

custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#select_marka').change(function(){

        $.post(
            'php/search.php',
            { marka_id:$('#select_marka').val()},
            function(res){
                $('#modele').html(res);
                $('#search-result').empty();
                $('#msg').empty();                  
                $('#cars').empty();
                $('#searchForm').trigger( 'reset' );
            }
        )

    });
    $('#select_model').change(function(){

        $.post(
            'php/search.php',
            { model_id:$('#select_model').val()},
            function(res){
                $('#cars').html(res);
                $('#search-result').empty();
                $('#msg').empty();

            }
        )
    });
    $('#select_car').change(function(){

        $.post(
            'php/search.php',
            { car_id:$('#select_car').val()},
            function(res){
                $('#info').html(res);
                PCL_TooltipUpdate();
                $('#search-result').empty();
                $('#msg').empty();

            }
        )
    });
```

});

Вот так всё начинает дико тормозить при уже 3-4 обращении, потом вообще список перестаёт подгружаться.
Так как будто память забивается.

если вынести часть JS кода непосредственно в файл search.php и отключить файлик js из search.php

```html
    <script>$('#select_model').change(function(){
  
   $.post(
    'php/search.php',
    { model_id:$('#select_model').val()},
    function(res){
     $('#cars').html(res);
     $('#search-result').empty();
     $('#msg').empty();
     
    }
   )
  });
</script>
<script>
  $('#select_car').change(function(){
  
   $.post(
    'php/search.php',
    { car_id:$('#select_car').val()},
    function(res){
     $('#info').html(res);
     PCL_TooltipUpdate();
     $('#search-result').empty();
     $('#msg').empty();
     
    }
   )
  });
});
</script>
```

всё работает без тормозов. В чём дело, подскажите?
как я вижу проблемы выполнения кода в файле search.php... но почему?
P.S. Мне тут подсказывают что это не JS a jQuery))) Да. извините. Не обратил внимание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый раз, когда Вы подключаете файл `"custom.js"` в `search.php`, он грузится в страницу, и код в нем выполняется. Каждый раз к событию `$('#select_marka').change` добавляется новый обработчик. Все эти обработчики выстреливают, обновляют части html и снова многократно грузят `"custom.js"`. Количество обработчиков увеличивается в геометрической прогрессии. Оставьте только `"custom.js"` в `head`.

```
$('#cars').on('change', '#select_model', function(){

$('#info').on('change', '#select_car', function(){
```

---

> я не пойму почему если непосредственно в файле search код то всё
>   работает идеально

Работает не идеально. То же самое явление присутствует и в таком случае, но в меньшем масштабе - Вы добавляете одинаковые обработчики только к `$('#select_model').change`, и эти обработчики сбрасываются (так как пересоздается кусок страницы) в момент, когда Вы меняете марку машины.

---

> как тогда исправить?

```
$(document).on('change', '#select_marka', function(){ 
  ...
});
$(document).on('change', '#select_model', function(){ 
  ...
});
$(document).on('change', '#select_car', function(){
  ...
});
```

Comment: Если просто оставлю custom.js в head, то файл search его не подхватывает.  И я не пойму почему если непосредственно в файле search код то всё работает идеально!

Comment: @SergioVorontsov Я не знаю, что значит технический термин "не подхватывает". Однако, я написал, что надо изменить в js, чтобы "подхватывал".

Comment: @SergioVorontsov Я написал Вам, что происходит в Вашем коде. Это понятно?

Comment: вместо $('#select_model').change(function(){
написал
$('#cars').on('change', '#select_model', function(){
не работает вообще

Comment: и как вы посоветовали не получается и
если пишу так
$(document).on('change', '#select_model', function(){

начинает тормозить(также как и при подключении файла скрипта к search.php)

custom.js и так подключен в index.php, но если не подключить его в search.php то вообще не видит.
первая часть custom.js срабатывает отлично, и данные обрабатываются нормально, список моделей заполняется, а дальше не идёт.

Comment: прописал $(document).on('change',.....

Comment: во всех трёх случаях и теперь работает, пока без тормозов, без подключения в файл search.php, теперь только в index.php прописано. Но опять же, не уверен что правильно это сделал.

$(document).on('change', '#select_marka', function(){
$(document).on('change', '#select_model', function(){
$(document).on('change', '#select_car', function(){

Comment: @SergioVorontsov Нет, это неправильно. Вы добавляете новые обработчики событий в обработчиках событий. Теперь их количество растет в арифметической прогрессии.

Comment: а как тогда исправить? То что вы предложили выше, не работает почему-то.