# Одна Entity и Две @OneToOne анотации

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-jpa

В таблице Location содержится информация которая должна выбираться согласно связи **characters.origin_id reference to location.id**
и **characters.location_id reference to location.id**.
Два поля сущности ссылаются на на поле id другой сущности в зависимости от значения записанного в  location_id и origin_id. но проблема в том что работает только location_id связь. Не пойму почему. Что-то я упустил....

**например**

```
characters -> id=1, name="Jim", origin_id=5, location_id=56
location -> id=5, name="Kyiv"
            id=56, name="London"
```

При выборке данных я получаю

`Location origin.name = "London" и Location location.name = "London"`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "characters")
public class Character implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private Long origin_id;
    @Column
    private Long location_id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "origin_id", insertable = false, updatable = false )
    private Location origin;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id", insertable = false, updatable = false )
    private Location location;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Один-к-одному" не подходит, так как одному `Character` соответствуют два `Location`-а.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // !!!
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "origin_id", insertable = false, updatable = false )
private Location origin;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // !!!
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "location_id", insertable = false, updatable = false )
private Location location;
```

---

Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - [Вынес JS код в отдельный файл. Тормозит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1005563/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81-js-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%a2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82)

Comment: @ManyToOne вариант я тоже пробовал, всёравно Location origin, Location location пишет одно и то же значение.
вот как SQL правильно выводит нужные мне данные:
```lang-sql
    SELECT c.name, l.name, o.name FROM characters c
    JOIN locations l ON c.location_id = l.id 
    JOIN locations o ON c.origin_id = o.id
    WHERE c.id = 11
```

Comment: не могу найти ошибку. В консоль выводит правильно! а в jsp одно и то же значение

Comment: @SergioVorontsov Покажите, как Вы выводите в консоль и в jsp.

Comment: Вот так в консоль:
***System.out.println("characterService = " + characterService.findById(453L));***
```characterService = Character{id=453, name='Vasia', origin=Location{name='Kharkov'}, location=Location{name='Kyiv'}} ```

вот так в JSP
***model.addAttribute("charList", characterService.findById(453L));***
```<c:forEach items="${charList}" var="cr" >
         origin: ${cr.origin.name}
         location: ${cr.location.name}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: всё, нашёл. getter и setter неправильно записаны были!

Comment: @SergioVorontsov Молодец!